# How to compare strings in which appears similar characters but different char codes?

Tags: javascript, string-comparison, keycode

I have the problem with comparing strings with different char codes but similar characters like the following:

```
console.log('³' === '3') // false;
```

False value from the code above because of different char codes:

```
console.log('³'.charCodeAt(0)) // 179
console.log('3'.charCodeAt(0)) // 51
```

What is a universal solution to convert values to be equals? I need it because I need to compare all numbers like `1,2,3,4,5....`

Thanks

Comment: Can you give us a well-defined definition of "similar characters"? Are you only worried about ten digit characters?

Comment: JavaScript doesn't see that they're similar, it just sees the char codes which are different...

Comment: @qxz yes I'm worried about only digit characters

Comment: @Andrew L Thanks Captain Obvious!

Comment: How are you defining equivalence? "Look similar" isn't really deterministic.

Comment: @Erik also, it might benefit you not to be sarcastic when seeking help.

Comment: Those aren't similiar to a computer, in fact they are completely different, the first one isn't even numeric, and can't be parsed to a number.

Comment: @Erik you haven't - you've just said "similar." If you want to compare "similar" things, you first need a concrete definition of "similar."

Comment: It doesn't matter what the other guy says or does, its your job to show respect. Anyway, what you need to do is tell the computer which ones are similar once, and then let the computer check that later.

Comment: Couldn't you just replace those characters with their corresponding digits before comparing...?

Comment: ^ that, create a map.

Comment: @Ant P So anyway I'm looking for advice to resolve this automatically

Comment: @qxz Maybe I could but my map will be very huge :(

Comment: Yes, probably as huge as the maps used by plugins -> https://github.com/mplatt/fold-to-ascii/blob/master/lib/ascii-folder.js

Comment: @Erik So you're interested in _every_ "digit-like" character?

Comment: @Erik how? The characters are not related in any way. It's impossible to resolve this problem without defining "similar."

Comment: @Erik Where is your input coming from? What is the context for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look into ASCII folding, which is primarily used to convert accented characters to unaccented ones. There's a JS library for it [here](https://github.com/mplatt/fold-to-ascii).

For your provided example, it will work - for other examples, it might not. It depends on how the equivalence is defined (nobody but you knows what you mean by "similar" - different characters are different characters).

If you know all of the characters that you want to map already, the easiest way will simply be to define a mapping yourself:

```
var eqls = function(first, second) {
    var mappings = { '³': '3', '3': '3' };

    if (mappings[first]) {
        return mappings[first] == mappings[second];
    }

    return false;
}

if (eqls('³', '3')) { ... }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Comment: `if (eqls('³', '3')!==false) { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

There is no "universal solution"

If you've only to deal with digits you may build up your "equivalence table" where for each supported character you define a "canonical" character.

For example

```
var eqTable = []; // the table is just an array

eqTable[179] = 51; // ³ --> 3
/* ... */
```

Then build a simple algorythm to turn a string into its canonical form

```
var original,         // the source string - let's assume original=="³3"
var canonical = "";   // the canonical resulting string

var i,
    n,
    c;

n = original.length;
for( i = 0; i < n; i++ )
{
    c = eqTable[ original.charCodeAt( i ) ];
    if( typeof( c ) != 'undefined' )
    {
        canonical += String.fromCharCode( c );
    }
    else
    {
        canonical += original[ i ]; // you *may* leave the original character if no match is found
    }
}

// RESULT: canonical == "33"
```

Comment: Why not use an associative array? Simpler than dealing with all the existence stuff in a regular one.

Comment: Don't you have to deal with the "existence stuff" with an associative array when you parse a string? I mean: even if you use an associative array you have to check if there is a match and decide what to do if a match is not found.

Comment: Sorry, yes, you do, but it's a little simpler, more flexible and less obscure (e.g. you can work with string literals instead of ASCII codes, as you're forced to with array indices).